# Bootstrap enable shadow

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to add shadow in Bootstrap on this div

```
<div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">Regular shadow</div>
```

In [GetBootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/shadows/) documentation it says

> "While shadows on components are disabled by default in Bootstrap and
>   can be enabled via $enable-shadows"

In which file/place do I actually add this?

I have looked around but most answers seems to refer to something called `scss` and some build process `npm run build`. All this seems overkill for the need. Is there an "easy" way to activate shadows in Bootstrap, like a script tag?

(I'm using Django, Bootstrap)

Comment: I've been using bootstrap for so long, and I just noticed this feature.. Commenting here to follow up for an answer

Comment: Will this CSS path help? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: @yinsweet That did the trick, it seems it is the flavour of Bootstrap that excluded Shadows (as Getbootstrap indicate in their text). I downloaded Stackpath and referenced to it as a file, and it worked. Meanwhile, using Getbootstrap, either as CDN or as a file, it didn't work. Thanks. If you reply to the question, I will credit it.

Comment: @Jaco glad that you find what is working now. Thanks for your kind offer. It's fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this with a **some** CDN bootstrap distributions.

You need to manage your own bootstrap distribution via `npm install bootstrap`

Once done go to the `node_modules\bootstrap\scss`

Create a file called `_custom.scss` inside that folder with the following content

```
$enable-shadows: true
```

Use the local distribution in your HTML

**References**

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/

Comment: Thanks, can you activate shadows without using Node Package Manager and SCSS?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, it is according to Bootstrap Documentation. Keep the question open, If someone has a workaround. You will get notified

Comment: Thanks a lot Supun De Silva, then I need to spend some time getting to know this framework, I keep it open until I achieve some better understanding.

Comment: Did you manage to find a better approach by any chance ?

Comment: The one I used finally was using Stackpath CDN. I seems the GetBootstrap CDN deliberately hadn't included shadows. This of course does not exclude your answer, just a version of the same. So, perhaps you need to modify saying "some CDN" does not include shadows. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was using rails with bootstrap, and also couldn't figure out where to add `$enable-shadows: true` as per [bootstrap 5 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/shadows/#examples).

For me, the answer was I didn't need to add it, I tried the shadow examples and they worked right away (I can't explain *why*, just that **shadows worked without me having to enable them!**)

```
<div class="shadow-none p-3 mb-5 bg-light rounded">No shadow</div>
<div class="shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">Small shadow</div>
<div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">Regular shadow</div>
<div class="shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">Larger shadow</div>
```

[image]

Note: here's confirmation that I *didn't* add the `$enable-shadows` as directed by the bootstrap docs:

[image]